# States not being applied with angular ui router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am having an issue with ui router where the state is not being triggered on a url.

On navigation to /#/dashboard/ the $state.current is set to abstract true with no state selected within.

No error messages are being thrown on $stateChangeError

JS -

```
var app = angular.module('frame', ['ui.router']);
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', function($stateProvider,    $locationProvider) {

    $stateProvider
        .state('dashboard', {
            url: '/dashboard/',
            views: {
                'header@': {
                    template: 'header'
                },
                'nav@': {
                    template: 'nav'
                },
                'main@': {
                    template: 'main'
                }
            }
        });

    // $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]).
run(['$browser', '$rootScope', '$state', function($browser, $rootScope, $state){
    // $browser.baseHref = function() { return '../'; };

    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", console.log.bind(console));

    console.log(window.location);

    $rootScope.state = $state;

}]);
```

html -

```
<body>
    <div ui-view="header">
    </div>
    <nav ui-view="nav">
    </nav>
    <main ui-view="main">
    </main>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link that throughly explains how to use Absolute Names,

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views

Comment: How does this know what url to display under?

Comment: Nevermind, i removed the @ in my example and that is it working, can't believe how simple that was to get working

Comment: Hoped I helped, Happy coding! :)